# Running jq query on alternating object type

Tags: jq

I have json file with lots of data about image files. It has this structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "graphic": "filename",
    "export_params": {
      "uses": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "graphic": "filename2",
    "export_params": []
  },
  ...
]
```

Most objects in this array has full `export_params` info, but sometimes it is just empty array. I've tried using this jq query

```
.[] | [.id, .graphic, .export_params.uses[], .export_params.export_type ] | @csv
```

to turn it into csv, but it broke on a line, where it found first "empty `export_params`" key. How can I bypass problem with different object type (most cases it's object, when empty, it's array - I think this is what causes my query to fail)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy part of this question is handling empty arrays and missing "export_type" values, e.g.

```
.[]
| [.id,
   .graphic,
   (.export_params.uses?[] // ""),
   (.export_params.export_type? // "") ]
| @csv
```

But what if `.uses` is an array with more than one item in it?  That would potentially mean a variable number of values
in the rows, which might cause problems.

To restrict consideration to the first item in `.uses`, you could use `first`:

```
.[]
| [.id,
   .graphic,
   first(.export_params.uses?[] // ""), 
   (.export_params.export_type? // "") ]
| @csv
```

### An alternative approach

To avoid clutter, it might be preferable to tweak the objects before querying them, e.g. along these lines:

```
.[]
| .export_params |= (if . == [] then {uses: [""]} else . end)
| [.id, 
   .graphic,
   .export_params.uses[0], 
   .export_params.export_type ]
| @csv
```

Comment: Damn, I've tried using question mark but it seems I did not understand how to use it properly ... that was close :) Your very first solution works as both keys (if exist) will return a maximum of single value. Dunno why array was used in this case. Thanks for the alrernative approach as well. Interesting way of handling such "variable" case and simplifying the data.